# Usage of "schon mal" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I know that "schon mal" means "yet, already, ever" and such things but when i try to insert one of those meanings in this sentence, it does not sound right:

> Können sie es **schon mal** verpacken, bitte? Ich komme gleich wieder!"

So it sounds like; "Can you pack this already?" or something like that, which sounds a bit wrong. What would be the literal meaning of schon mal here?

Comment: Meanwhile sounds a lot more better, though I never found such a translation.

Comment: Well, there aren't ever one to one translations for semantical context.

Comment: I would translate it as "Can you please **go ahead and** pack it?" The reason I wouldn't translate it as "meanwhile" is because the first sentence makes sense on its own without the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Können sie es schon mal verpacken, bitte? Ich komme gleich wieder!"
> >     I know that "schon mal" means "yet, already, ever"

That won't be totally wrong, just a bit jolty.

The probably better translation of ***schon mal*** in that (timing based) context is ***meanwhile***:

> "Can you wrap that **meanwhile** please? I'll be back in a moment."

Or even mention the timing context prior to the request:

> "I'll be back in a moment. Can you wrap that **meanwhile** please?"

---

> I know that "schon mal" means "yet, already, ever"

- these refer to a different context more like

  > Hast Du / Haben Sie **schon mal**

  (also see **jemals** please)

Comment: Maybe you also want to cover "da kein einem schon mal der Kragen platzen" (particle, no "time" background).

Comment: @tofro _"(particle, no "time" background)"_ Doesn't my answer cover that correctly in the 2nd part?

Comment: I don't think so. Neither "yet, already, or ever" nor "jemals" fit here. "schon mal" is used as an excuse here.

Comment: @tofro I'd appreciate if you like to add another answer, or edit mine accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that *schon* modifies *mal* modifies *verpacken*. [schon mal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon_mal) is adverbial of time, basically *gleich*, *bald* (*soon*, not strictly *immediately*) and it carries a sense of colloquialism denoting a simple task, so simple that *bitte* would be too formal, though *bitte schon mal* would be a compromise. So, for imperative speech, it leaves a choice of when the action has to be done, but it is usually accompanied with a constrained "... bevor ich zurück komme". In that sense, *schon mal* is almost redundant. "Bitte verpacken Sie das, bevor ich zurück komme!" or just "Bitte verpacken Sie das zeitgemäß" (in due time). However, it can also stand on it's own. The sense *bevor* becomes very apparent in "*Ich habe da schon mal was vorbereitet*" (I have [already] prepared something), thus also "Ich werde schon mal etwas vorbereiten". Your observation, that "do that already" sounds denigrating is not completely wrong. On the one hand, if not accompanied by a time limit, one is left guessing and the implication is to do it **rather sooner than later**. On the other hand, it appears in the accusation "Das hättest du schon mal tun können" (you could have done that already). Note that *bereit* carries over very well to *ready*. In fact, **bereits** exists: "Du kannst das bereits einpacken".

*schon* on it's own means *already, yet*. "Ich habe das schon gemacht".

*mal, Mal* designates a time and is largely synonymous with *einmal* (once), and perceived as a shortening of that. Although, of course, it also appears in *zweimal* (twice) and the like, only *einmal* stands in for a time. "can you pack that once yet" doesn't have the right ring though <sup>[1]</sup>.

Under influence of *einmal* (*irgendwann* "unspecified time"), *schon mal* expresses a restriction on *einmal*, ie. *schon einmal*, which exists in the same sense, and, if not for syntactic or logic reasons, the *ein* is simply contracted and elided "schon'nmal". In that sense, it should be written as a compound, as are *beidemal*, *vielmal*, *niemals* and the like; wiktionary indexes colloquial [schomma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schomma) and *schonmal*, but Duden-online does not.

Since *-al* is an adjectival (noun-)suffix from Latin *-alis*, I'd presume that *-al* is short enough to be perceived as a suffix, as if GEN *beidem*+*-al*. I'm not aware of an etymological tangent along those lines, but at least a phonetic argument could be made. "Kannst du da mal gucken?" just flows better. Edit: I guess *dezimal* would be an example of this, where the common prefix today is *dezi-*, but the *m* comes from Lat. *decem*.

A contrived, but helpful translation would be *nicely*, since *schon* apparently derives from *schön*. "Kannst du das schon mal schön verpacken?" wouldn't be unheared of, and that's where the stark contrast to "already" becomes apparent.

Still though, the sentence could be transformed for clarity.

> a. (Du (((kannst) schonma) ((das) verpacken))).
>
> (You ((can) already) (pack (that) up)).

Whereas "Du kannst das schonma verpacken" would be a bit closer to "damn already", but I'm not firm with syntax tree building.

Also helpful might be an analogy to *einfach, zweifach* (one times, two times) and *einfach* (simple), thus: "You can pack that up, easy".

<sub>[1]: On that note, you have to wonder just a bit about *jetzt* (now, viz *gleich*, *bald*), which sounds like a mix of *yet* and the *-ce* in *once*--*yetce* :D but *je* has a very difficult history. *once* stems from a genitive construction; *jetzt* is amenable to a superficial analysis of *je* + *zu*; Dunno if that *zu* marks the genetive. [de.wt/jetzt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jetzt) mentions "*Ursprüngliche Bedeutung wie **heutzutage***", thus we may think of **schonzumal*, comparable to *dazumal* or just *zumal*. Compare also *zubereiten* and the like.</sub>

Comment: The paragraph starting with *Since -al is an adjectival (noun-)suffix from Latin* is entirely off and destroys an otherwise acceptable answer.

Comment: I didn't know how to package that up as an argument about phonetics, and maybe that would be selling it short. I was reluctant to make an allusion to "soon-ish", so I'm aware of the problems. Sadly there's no indication that *soon* and *schon* were related.